# Upper-bound of mutual information given one distribution fixed

Tags: machine-learning, mutual-information

I encountered this problem while estimating some information loss functions, however I am not an expert at information theory. Given two variables $X,Y$, the mutual information is defined as $I(X,Y)=\int P(X,Y) log \dfrac{P(X,Y)}{P(X)P(Y)}dX dY$. My question is, assume that the distribution of $X$ is clear, how to estimate the upper-bound of $I(X,Y)$ in terms of correlation/dependence of $Y$ with/on $X$?

Two easy case are that $X,Y$ are independent and the same, where $I(X,Y)$ would be zero and the entropy of $X$ respectively. In fact, $I(X,Y)$ is non-negative, and the entropy of $X$ is the upper-bound of $I(X,Y)$ if $X$ is fixed. I wonder whether we could have a sharper bound of the mutual information by some methods (e.g. correlation) in the general case.

BTW, let $H(V)$ denote the entropy of a random variable $V$. By some simple calculations,  we have $I(X,Y)=H(X)-H(X|Y)=H(Y)-H(Y|X)=H(X)+H(Y)-H(X,Y)$. I guess that we can directly get the answer by estimating $H(X|Y)$.

Comment: The quantity $I(X,Y)$ you've given there is not what is commonly referred to as mutual information. Do you want to bound your $I(X, Y)$, or mutual information?

Comment: @Oxonon Thanks for your reply. I found I just missed the logarithm symbol in mutual information (I fixed it now). In fact the mutual information is concerned.

Comment: A bound using correlation won't work. Zero mutual information implies independence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bound using correlation won't work. Suppose $I(X,Y) \leq f(\text{Cov}(X,Y))$ for $f$ such that $f(0) = 0$. Then $\text{Cov}(X,Y) = 0 \implies I(X,Y) = 0$. But $I(X,Y) = 0 \iff X \perp Y$, hence this is a constradiction. Now suppose you want a bound with $f(0) > 0$ and $f$ is monotonic. Then rescaling of the random variables $X,Y$ could make the bound arbitrarily loose.

Comment: I think your idea and example are quite reasonable. Thanks, I should find something else to control it. By the way, do you have any recommending reference on finding more accurate bounds of the mutual information?

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: For a neural network, this term appears in the loss function. I would like to have a computational upper-bound, then update the weight w.r.t. this bound in order to minimize/control the loss indirectly.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend that you seek standard methods of fitting neural networks. Thousands of researchers have spent years looking at those. Coming up with novel ways of training these is fine if you're a researcher, but if that's the case, this isn't the place to ask.